# How to convert a folder with subfolders to gz format

Tags: linux, unix

Is there any command to convert a folder with subfolders to gz format in Linux. I don't need a format with tar.gz and I need only with foldername.gz.

Comment: `tar -zcvf archive-name.tar.gz <directory-name>` Take a look at: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-compress-a-whole-linux-or-unix-directory/

Comment: I don't want with tar.gz , I need with directory name.gz

Comment: What about this command: `gzip filename.gz  /<path_to_dir>/<target_dir>`

Comment: This command is not working where there are subfolders exist. please suggest any command to convert it to gz

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93139/can-i-zip-an-entire-folder-using-gzip I am not sure what would happen if you use `tar` command without tar in archive's name

Comment: `gzip` can only compress single files or streams, it is not a container like tar or zip or others. You can't compress a directory into a single file with `gzip`

Comment: Thanks for your information

Answer (score 1):

You can use tar command as below for compressing :
tar -zvcf .gz

And you can uncompress it using tar only as below :
tar -xvzf .gz